# How to get information about maven dependency from source code?

Tags: java, maven

I'm new to Java and Maven.

I'm following this tutorial about Cucumber in Java but it doesn't mention about Maven dependency such as groupId or artifactId of modules that related to Cucumber.

https://cucumber.netlify.app/docs/guides/browser-automation/

My question is that from information of the code base, how can I get information to insert to pom.xm?

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

Comment: https://cucumber.netlify.app/docs/installation/java/ This is in their official documentation. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the above classes following are the dependencies I use, But there can be compatibility issues with your requirements and versions. Try the below and see if works, else you will have to find it from the maven repository

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version> <!--Not sure the version-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version> <!--Not sure the version-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version> <!--Not sure the version-->
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you *specific* question will be answered by looking into the cucumber installation guides.

Your *general* question ("How to find the Maven dependencies for given imports?") is not truly solvable. You can, of course, take the qualified class names and look them up in https://search.maven.org/, but this will at best narrow down the search, and probably won't tell you which exact versions of the artifacts you should use.

Answer (score 1):

Any stable released version should be good to use. Example, I see you can use 
[3.141.59](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/3.141.59/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)
Like:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```